# Regularity for the critical case $p=2^*$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Suppose i have a weak solution $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ of the problem

\begin{cases} 
       -\Delta u = |u|^{2^*-2}u, & x \in \Omega \\
        u=0, & x \in \partial \Omega
   \end{cases}

And $\Omega$ is as regular as you want. I now need to jump the solution to $C^2$, but the problem is that I think $f(x) = |x|^{2^*-2}x $ is not Holder continuous, so I can't apply the usual theorems. How can I override this?

Comment: Are able to assume $u$ is non-negative? $f$ is smooth away from $0$ so you can recover your regularity theorems by making this assumption

Comment: @JackT yes i need to assume that it is strictly positive, but if i do that how is it holder continuous? I can't see it, the derivative is not bounded.

Comment: Can you do $L^p$ theory instead?

Comment: @altdelay I agree that my comment is incomplete. My thought process was if $u \in C^2 (\Omega)$, non-negative, and you only cared about interior regularity then on each $\Omega' \subset \subset \Omega$, $u \geqslant c>0$ (by strong max principle). Since $f$ is smooth away from zero this suggested to me that you should be able to adjust the usual regularity theorems to make them work

Comment: That being said, @ArcticChar's suggestion to use $L^p$ theory definitely seems more promising to me.